# Array exists 300ms later as expected

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I´m loading an Array from a service I connected with a PouchDB Database. From there I build an array and return it to the component.

**My service**

```
getBooks() {
  let ar:BibleBook[] = [];

  this.db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true
  }).then(function (result) {
    result.rows.map((row) => {
      ar.push(row.doc);
      ar.sort((a, b) => a.id < b.id ? -1 : a.id > b.id ? 1 : 0);
    });
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  return ar;
}
```

**My component**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.bibleBooks = this.db.getBooks();
  this.selectBibleBook(this.bibleBooks[0]);
}
```

The problem: `this.bibleBooks[0]` is undefined because the answer from my service comes 300ms later. How can I wait until `this.bibleBooks` is a valid array?

I don't want to work with `setTimeout()`. Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Don't you have to `await` for `this.db.getBooks();` ? I guess it's an `async` request

Comment: Yea..but the browser seems to call the second line ealier than the first line.. and so I get undefined..

Comment: @eleinad - Yes, that's the nature of asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an `async` issue. For the explanation, in `getBooks` you are not waiting for `result` before returning `ar`. Then, when the function is called, the array is empty.

It should fix your issue :

**Service**

```js
async getBooks() {
  let ar: BibleBook[] = [];

  try {
    const result = await this.db.allDocs({
      include_docs: true
    });

    return result.rows
      .map((row) => row.doc)
      .sort((a, b) => a.id < b.id ? -1 : a.id > b.id ? 1 : 0);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Component**

```js
async ngOnInit() {
  this.bibleBooks = await this.db.getBooks();
  this.selectBibleBook(this.bibleBooks[0]);
}
```

Comment: your async function does not have an `await` anywhere, therefore the code is still doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @K48, it's just a mistake.

Comment: @Nenroz nice answer but I have nitpick. Either use `results.forEach(...` or `return results.map(...`

Comment: @AluanHaddad you're right ! I just made the `async` fixes from the original question, but I'm pretty sure it can be optimized

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite everything using async/await.

```
async getBooks() {
  try {
    const ar: BibleBook[] = (await this.db
      .allDocs({ include_docs: true }))
      .map(row => row.doc);

    ar.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);

    return ar;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

async ngOnInit() {
  this.bibleBooks = await this.db.getBooks();
  this.selectBibleBook(this.bibleBooks[0]);
}
```

The trick is:

- Your `getBooks()` function won't complete until you fetch data from the database, thanks to `await`ing the database call.
- You won't try to `selectBibleBook()` until `getBooks()` completes, thanks to `await getBooks()`.

I've also simplified your `.map()` a bit for cleaner code.

Comment: yep. Added brackets